# How to convert and return a generic composition if limitations are also used?

Tags: c#, generics

I want to create an OperationFactory. This OperationFactory should return an Operation based on the OperationRequest if one is passed in.

The Operation itself has a Property to return an OperationResult.

The OperationResult is also generic.

In the view of my application, I'm getting some information that I'm able to create and an OperationRequest. Also I'll have an OperationHandler there. The OperationHandler will use the OperationsFactory to retrieve the correct/desired Operation.

Which will be executed by the OperationHandler.

```cs
interface IOperationFactory
{
    Tout Operation<Tout, TResult, Tin, T>(Tin request)
        where Tin : IOperationRequest
        where TResult : IOperationResult<T>
        where Tout : BaseOperation<T>;
}

interface IOperationHandler
{
    IOperationResult<T> Handle<T>(IOperationRequest request);
}

interface IOperationResult<T>
{
    Guid Id { get; }
    Guid RequestId { get; }
    T Value { get; }
}

/* Here's the part that is making my problems, its part of the OperationsFactory: */
public Tout Operation<Tout, TResult, Tin, T>(Tin request)
    where Tout : BaseOperation<T>
    where TResult : IOperationResult<T>
    where Tin : IOperationRequest
{
    if (request is AddItemsRequest)
    {
        var finalType = request as AddItemsRequest;
        Type target = typeof(Tout);
        return (Tout) new AddItemsOperation(request);
    }
    throw new InvalidOperationException();
}

public sealed class AddItemsRequest : IOperationRequest
{
    public AddItemsRequest(List<Item> items, string site)
    {
        Id = Guid.NewGuid();
        Items = items;
        Site = site;
    }

    public Guid Id { get; }
    public List<Item> Items { get; }
    public string Site { get; }
}

public sealed class AddItemsOperation : BaseOperation<Tuple<IToken, IBasket>>
{
    private readonly IApi _api;
    private readonly IToken _token;

    public AddItemsOperation(
        IOperationRequest request,
    )
    : this(api, request)
    { }

    public AddItemsOperation(Api api, IOperationRequest request)
    : base(request)
    {
        _api = api;
    }


        public override IOperationResult<Tuple<IToken, IBasket>> Result()
        {

            /* Implementation Details Removed */

            return new OperationResult
                <Tuple<IToken, IBasket>>(
                    Request.Id,
                );
        }

        private AddItemsRequest AddItemsRequest(IOperationRequest request)
        {
            if (!(request is AddItemsRequest))
            {
                throw new InvalidOperationException($"Supported type is only {typeof(AddItemsRequest).Name}");
    }

    return request as AddItemsRequest;
}
```

Cannot convert type 'AddItemsRequest' to 'Tout'

Comment: its tough to help troubleshoot with incomplete code.  you can remove your implementation details, but you're only giving us parts of some types and not every class and interface in your abstraction -- for instance `IOperationRequest` is missing.  can you provide a concise sample code that captures that problem and that builds or at least fails with an exception we can see? in that last method it seems like you are passing the parameter when the methods returns, is that where the error is occurring?

Comment: At first glance, I think that `AddItemsRequest` should return and instance of `AddItemsOperation`which implements `BaseOperation<T>` and is compatible with the generic constraints on `TOut` which is ... `where Tout : BaseOperation<T>` -- meaning `TOut` is expecting an "operation" and you are setting it to the "request" instance.

Comment: The code in the post, is missing one " } "  at the end.

Comment: Example Code can be found here: https://dotnetfiddle.net/YT6Qfc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could you try to return with safe cast:

```
return new AddItemsOperation(
    request
) as Tout;
```